# Unusual Google Sitelinks for "superuser"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, google

If you google "superuser" one of the sitelink options is a user account.  Is that suppose to happen?

[image]

Comment: What? No freehand circles? What's in that picture? I can't see anything!

Comment: Actually, that's *two* user accounts: Community and Nick Josevski.

Comment: This isn't really limited to SU. It happens when searching for all 4 sites.

Answer (score 6):

Good point, I blocked the 3+ users that were showing up here via the [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

No offense, I <3 all SU users, but I think we want stuff like /faq and /questions and /users in Google SiteLinks -- not individual users!

(we've done this before for SO and SF as well, so it's fairly common...)

Answer (score 3):

Those are known as sitelinks and Google Webmaster tools allows one to block them. Blocking links that shouldn't be there helps their algorithm, they say.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

That's google! They're giving you a result that may be relevant within the domain you searched for. It's normal, and totally not under anybody's control but google's. Sometimes it's helpful, but in fringe cases like this, maybe not so much.